# Listview with textview not focusable in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, focus

I have a sample code for my settop box and it must be uses by remote control unit(rcu) so not in touchable mode.I have a ListView in activity_main.xml and listview items in item.xml and i have to focus listview and buttonduzenle in non touchable mode i cant select listview with arrow keys can you help me?
My activity_main.xml looks like;

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/duyurubg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/lvMainn"
         android:layout_width="498dp"
         android:layout_height="285dp"
         android:dividerHeight="1dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
         android:divider="#CFD2CD"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonduzenle"
         android:layout_width="300dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         android:text="Düzenle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and item.xml looks like;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Konu:"
            android:textColor="#FBD333"
            android:textSize="20sp" >

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Mesaj:"
            android:textColor="#FBD333"
            android:textSize="20sp" >

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescrr"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="aaa"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPricee"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="bbb"
            android:textSize="20sp" >

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPriceee"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="bbb"
            android:textSize="20sp" >

        </TextView>
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/okunduu"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="bbb"
            android:textSize="20sp" >

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" and android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to my Listview in activity_main.xml and it works